Unit map for Closed Immersion (Q. Liu's AG, Ex. 2.2.13)
Let $f: X \to Y$ be a closed immersion of topological spaces and $F$ a sheaf on $Y$. In Liu's Algebraic Geometry exercise 2.2.13 (p 40) is asked to show that the the unit map $F \to f_*f^{-1}F$ is surjective. My guess is that it is actually an iso at stalks at points lying in the image $x \in f(X)$.
That's it is a zero map at points not in the image should be clear, as we can find open $U \subset Y-f(X)$, so stalks at $f_*(Bla)$ "not see" them.
I would like to clarify if following argumentation is correct or maybe contains gaps I overlooked:
Let denote by $(f^{-1}F)_{pre}$ the presheaf from page 37 which is usually introduced to obtain $f^{-1}F$ as its sheafification. We have a canon map of $(f^{-1}F)_{pre} \to f^{-1}F$ which is an iso on stalks by definition, and by functoriality we get a map of presheaves $f_*(f^{-1}F)_{pre} \to f_*f^{-1}F$. For general $f$, we know nothing about what happens on stalks with respect this map, but  in case of $f$ closed immersion it should be easy to check that that's an iso on stalks. (As side note, using univ property of sheafification this seemingly also implies (as stalks stay the same), one sees that sheafifiation $(f_*(f^{-1}F)_{pre})^{sh})$ is isomorphic to $f_*f^{-1}F$, what for general $f$ is also wrong.
On the other one hand one can canonically on local sections construct "by hand" $F \to f_*(f^{-1}F)_{pre}$ which by construction is iso at stalk of $x \in f(X)$, then composing with previous map would give that $F \to f_*f^{-1}F$ is indeed an iso at stalks of image points. Does the argumentation make sense?
If that's ok, are there quicker or say more "standard" ways to solve it, as I'm pretty sure that thhe presented approach (... if it is correct) is not the slickest way to do it.
The central motivation of this question is that in several lecture notes I read so far refering to this fact one often state this by obviously incomplete agument that this follows from that stalks of $F$ and $f_*f^{-1}F$ at points in image $f(X)$ are the same - a fact which is easy to check - but the subtilety is that its the counit which gives actually the iso at these stalks.

Why the downvote?

All of what you point out is standard and I do not think there is a slicker way, yet they are considered to be trivial in algebraic geometry, although I remember that all these stuffs were also hard to me when I begin to learn algebraic geometry.

@NguyễnXuânBách: Ok, I just wasn't sure if the way how I solved it is really the say "standard one" to approach this. Alternatively it could be also approached more abstractly by means of triangle identities; see see Prop. 2.3, Eqn 3; compare with discussion below this answer

Usually just taking stalks to show morphisms of sheaves are surjective/injective/isomorphic. I do not think adjunctions help since we need context in this case as the (co)units are not always isomorphisms.

@NguyễnXuânBách: But we have canonical composition $f^{-1}F \to f^{-1}f_*f^{-1}F \to f^{-1}F$ which is nothing but identity by the mentioned triangle identities. Then we can consider the stalks and observe that for $y=f(x)$ we have $f^{-1}F_x=F_y$ and left map is the unit map, and right is iso for $f$ closed immersion. That was the idea, essentially this just formalizing FShrike's argument from comments

I do not have time to follow other problems, but this seems weird to me. If we need to take the stalks, why don't we take immediately the stalks of the original morphism $F\to f_*f^{-1}F$. Moreover, right after we write the morphism $F\to f_*f^{-1}F$, we have to know the its definition and it already shows why the morphism is surjective. I am pretty sure that in all algebraic geometry class, your above proof should be the standard one.

@NguyễnXuânBách: sorry if that's take some time but I'm not sure, why it is the case that "right after we have written down the morphism $F \to f_*f^{-1}F$" we already see from its definition that "this already shows that its surjective". At the beginning we a priori only know abstractly about the existence of $F \to f_*f^{-1}F$, namely by adjunction we have $Hom(f^{-1}F, f^{-1}F) \cong Hom(F, f_*f^{-1}F)$ and our map corresp abstractly to identity of $f^{-1}F$. Now looking in detatils how the iso is obtained, on local sections at $V \subset X$ as canonical

composition $(f^{-1}F)(V) \xrightarrow{a} (f_(f^{-1}F){pre})(V) \xrightarrow{b} (f(f^{-1}F))(V)  \xrightarrow{c} (f_(f^{-1}F))(V) $. Passing to stalks, we observe that $a$ is always an iso at stalks and $c$ is even identity on local section level. (...both independently of $f$!) But $b$ is critical, I don't think that its "immediate" from just wring down that's an iso on stalks. Note, that sheafifying operation and $f_$ behave bad (=not commute in general). Is this the way you proposed in your last comment?

Oh now I see your problem. In fact, in the exercise in Liu's book that you cited, we construct the (co)units to give the adjunction (of course the other way is also possible), so you need to stick to only one argument so people can follow. The definition of $F\to f_*f^{-1}F$ is quite direct: over any open $U$ and $s\in F(U)$,  $f_*f^{-1}F(U)= f^{-1}F(f^{-1}U)$ and $s$ gives an element in $colim_{f(f^{-1}U)\subseteq V} F(V)$ ($U$ contains $f(f^{-1}U)$) so it gives an element in $f^{-1}F(f^{-1}U)$.

@NguyễnXuânBách: first, note that my last commnt has a typo: The domain of $a$ is $F(V)$ and not $f^{-1}(V)$ as claimed there. Then, the construction you wrote down is exactly the composition of my $a$ and $b$  (...$c$ is as remarked indentity). So map know how $s \in F(U)$ maps to $f^{-1}F(f^{-1}(U))=f_*f^{-1}F(U)$. Well, but is it clear at this stage that we a surjection?

Now we have the definition of $F\to f_*f^{-f}F$ so we know the definition of the induced maps between stalks. I think you should be able to carry the proof yourself. The point is that we will encounter a lot of statements like this one in algebraic geometry and there is no adjunction at all in many contexts. The logic of the exercise in Liu's book is fine. If you want to start with some adjunction and consider the morphism as some abstract one then that is ok too, we don't need to have similar thinking.
